# Was there any imperial nation whose home country was conquered but was able to retain its colonies?

Tags: imperialism

Has an imperial nation been conquered and the forces of the imperial nation then mainly came to their colonies. Even after the home nation gets captured the colonies are ruled and they don't revolt. Then the imperial nation re-conquers the home nation back with help from the immensely helpful colonies and then is able to re-establish itself?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I'm curious - what is the inspiration for this question; on the surface it is a pretty obscure edge case, but two different people have asked it.  Is there some significance that I'm missing?

Comment: Basically I had this question after watching alternate history of the world videos.

Comment: Thanks - your comment helped me to understand H:SE a little better. I need time to think it through, but I wanted to recognize that the question and the comment were very useful.

Comment: Whgat got are you thinkg?I mean what is there to think in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### France during WW2

After the fall of France in 1940 the Free France and its Free French Forces were formed to fight against the Axis powers. From colonial outposts in Africa, India, and the Pacific, Free France steadily took over more and more Vichy possessions.

After Operation Torch (the Allied landings in North Africa) Free France retook much of his north-African possession and the French Army of Africa switched allegiance to Free France. This caused the Axis to occupy Vichy in reaction.

The forces of Free France fought their way back into France, first by participating in the Allied invasion of Italy and then in the Normandy landings.

The [Wikipedia page of Free France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_France) has a lot of information, with a detailed maps of the colonies participating.